# Passing arguments in templates

Tags: c++, tree

I am implementing a Red black Tree where the insert function should have two templates, one for the item and the other for the key. I am passing the parameters in the insert function this way:

```
template <class Item, class Key>
void RedBlackTreeNode<Item, Key>::InsertKey(const Item *&T, const Key *&z)
```

I tried to pass an array(made up of random elements) in the second parameter, this way:

```
const int* pointer = &arr[i];
t1.InsertKey(//something else here// , pointer); //insert the tree and the node
```

However, I can't figure out what to pass as the first parameter in order to insert elements in the red black tree. What is the first parameter representing? I tried to pass the root of the tree, this way:

```
Node<int, int> n1;
t1.InsertKey(n1->root, pointer);
```

Unfortunately, this is not working.Any help please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is error you are getting?

Comment: If you're implementing a dictionary (also known as an associative array, or a map) then Item is probably the type of the values stored in the map.

Comment: I am getting three errors: Invalid arguments Candidates are:
void InsertKey(const int * &, const int * &), Field 'root' could not be resolved and base operand of ‘->’ has non-pointer type ‘Node<int, int>’

Comment: Why are you using pointers here?

Comment: I don't know another method of how I can implement the red black tree and I have the restriction of using two templates.

Comment: Why do you pass the parameters to InsertKey with "*&"? Do you want to pass a pointer, a reference, or does *& have a special meaning that I'm not aware of?

Comment: Pass by reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5789806/meaning-of-and-in-c

Comment: Ah, thank you for the link. Are you sure that is what you want? *& declares a reference to a pointer. Maybe you want to pass references to an Item and a Key like that: InsertKey(const Item &T, const Key &z)

Comment: But still, I can't figure out what to pass for 'const Item &T'

Answer (score 1):

If you're implementing a red black tree (or just even just a binary tree), you're insertion method just take the element to insert as parameter. You're inserting one `Item` that can be compared to another item, there is no notion of `Key`. If you want to create `Key`/`Value` container, you can just take an `std::pair<Key, Value>` item and compare on `item.first`, or something like this.

Here is a mock up of the code for the [binary search tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree#Insertion) insertion. You can start with that to add the properties that have to be kept for [red black tree insertion(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree#Insertion):

```
template <class Item>
void BinarySearchTreeNode<Item>::Insert(Item item)
{
   if (item < this->item)
   {
     if (this->leftChild == nullptr)
        this->leftChild = new BinarySearchTreeNode(item);
     else
        insert(this->leftChild, item);
   } 
   else 
   {
     if (this->rightChild == nullptr)
        this->rightChild = new BinarySearchTreeNode(item);
     else
        insert(this->rightChild, item);
   }
}
```

And here a example usage (assuming the rest of the implementation has been done):

```
BinarySearchTree<int> tree;


tree.Insert(1); // Call insert on root node
```

Comment: Therefore, my insertion method can't take two parameters?

Comment: @user3136756 It is not that it **cannot** take two parameters, but what would be the second one ? If you have a explanation/justification for the usage of the second parameter, go on :) But basic red black tree (or binary tree) take only one value or item to insert in the node.

Comment: Well, that was my question, I don't know what to pass for the second parameter. I was given this question to implement and there was stated that when adding an item both the key and the item should be both generic types(templates in C++). Therefore, I thought that I had to use two templates, but I am coming to conclusions that using two templates does not make any sense!