# What does *& mean?

Tags: c++, pointers, syntax, reference

What is the meaning of `Node *&front` the below linked list code extract in C++?

```
 FrontBackSpilit(head,a,b) 

 Node * FrontBackSpilit(Node * head, Node *&front, Node * &back)
```

Comment: Reference to a pointer

Comment: why we cannot use this   (Node * front)

Comment: @Raufjavid Because you are passing the pointer by value, so if you want to modify the pointer within the function (not the thing it is pointing at) it will not be reflected back outside the function, because only the copy of the pointer is modified within the function.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5789806/meaning-of-and-in-c

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Node *&front

this is a reference to pointer to instance of Node, so if you call FrontBackSpilit like:

```
Node* pNode1;
Node* pBack;
FrontBackSpilit(NULL, pNode1, pBack);
```

and FrontBackSpilit will do for example `front = new Node`, then pNode1 will be assigned this value.

If instead of `Node *&front` you would have `Node *front`, then assignment to front will not change pNode1.

Comment: It means by using this ( Node *&front )  we are passing reference not value..Am i Right.

Comment: It means Node* is passed by reference not by value.

Comment: @Raufjavid Yes. The *pointer* is being passed by *reference*. You can think of non-`const` reference parameters as "output parameters".

Comment: reference to pointer, this is actually equivalent to pointer to pointer : `Node **front`, then in function `*front = new Node;`, but its easier to access variable using `*&`

Comment: @marcinj@Joseph Mansfield@drescherjm  K...I understand..Thank You so much for your Help.