# Passing pointers by reference using int*& is causing odd problems

Tags: c++, pointers

I am writing the following to pass pointers by reference. However, when I try to dereference the pointers, it is giving unexpected values.

```
void passPointers(int* &a){
    int p = 5;
    a = &p;
}
int main(){
  int x = 3;
  int *y= &x;
  cout<<"y is "<<y<<" *y is "<<*y<<endl;
  passPointers(y);
      
  //cout<<"y is "<<y<<" *y is "<<*y<<endl;//line a
  cout<<" *y is "<<*y<<endl;//It returns 5
  return 0;
}
```

If I uncomment line a, it returns address of y , *y returns some unknown integer value.Am I breaking some norms of C++.
I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5789806/meaning-of-and-in-c) link while writing this code.
I am using g++ 7.3.0

Comment: `p` is destroyed immediately after execution leaves `passPointers()`. Thus the pointer becomes dangling, and reading the pointed value gives you undefined behavior.

Comment: You're returning the address of a local variable. That variable does not exist outside of that function, and accessing it is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
void passPointers(int* &a){
    int p = 5;
    a = &p;
} // p dies here
```

The pointer becomes dangling because you're binding it to the address of a local variable.