# *& vs & in passing variable to function

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, swap

I'm trying to understand reference and pointer in C++, and I stumble upon this

```
#include<iostream> 
using namespace std; 

void swap(char * &str1, char * &str2) 
{ 
char *temp = str1; 
str1 = str2; 
str2 = temp; 
} 

int main() 
{ 
const char *str1 = "GEEKS"; 
const char *str2 = "FOR GEEKS"; 
swap(str1, str2); 
cout<<"str1 is "<<str1<<endl; 
cout<<"str2 is "<<str2<<endl; 
return 0; 
}
```

What is `*&` in the function Swap, and compare to `&` (Pass by reference) I have learned, is there any different in performance, or how do they work, what should I use?

```
void swap(char &str1, char &str2) 
{ 
char temp = str1; 
str1 = str2; 
str2 = temp; 
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Meaning of \*& and \*\*& in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5789806/meaning-of-and-in-c)

Comment: It depends what you need. `char&` is a reference to a `char` whereas `char*&` is a reference to a `char` pointer. Very different things.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I have already read this and it's a bit advanced for me, basically I want to understand why not just use `&`. In what situation `*&` is better than `&`.

Comment: @Phineas Your type is `char*`, not `char`, so the reference to this type is `char* &`, not `char &`. There is no "in what situation one is better". For a given type you use given syntax, that's all.

Answer (score 3):

Any type can be referenced in a declaration.

For example

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    const char *s = "Hello";

    const char * &reference_to_s = s;

    std::cout << reference_to_s << '\n';
}
```

The same program can be rewritten also the following way

```
#include <iostream>

using T = const char *;

int main()
{
    T s = "Hello";

    T & reference_to_s = s;

    std::cout << reference_to_s << '\n';
}
```

Thus the parameters of the function `swap`

```
void swap(char * &str1, char * &str2);
```

are references to pointers to non-constant strings/arrays.

In the first call there is an attempt to swap values of two pointers that are passed by reference.

However this call

```
swap(str1, str2);
```

is incorrect because the arguments have the type `const char *` while the parameters declared without the qualifier `const`.

Using the alias declaration shown above your program can be written like

```
#include <iostream>

using T = const char *;

void swap( T &s1, T &s2 )
{
    T temp = s1;
    s1 = s2;
    s2 = temp;
}

int main()
{
    T str1 = "GEEKS"; 
    T str2 = "FOR GEEKS"; 

    std::cout << "str1 is " << str1 << '\n'; 
    std::cout << "str2 is " << str2 << '\n';
    std::cout << '\n';

    swap( str1, str2 ); 

    std::cout << "str1 is " << str1 << '\n'; 
    std::cout << "str2 is " << str2 << '\n'; 
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Its output is

```
str1 is GEEKS
str2 is FOR GEEKS

str1 is FOR GEEKS
str2 is GEEKS
```

The next step to make references more clear is substitute the alias declaration and the non-template function `swap` for a template function `swap`.

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
void swap( T &s1, T &s2 )
{
    T temp = s1;
    s1 = s2;
    s2 = temp;
}

int main()
{
    const char *str1 = "GEEKS"; 
    const char *str2 = "FOR GEEKS"; 

    std::cout << "str1 is " << str1 << '\n'; 
    std::cout << "str2 is " << str2 << '\n';
    std::cout << '\n';

    swap( str1, str2 ); 

    std::cout << "str1 is " << str1 << '\n'; 
    std::cout << "str2 is " << str2 << '\n'; 
    std::cout << '\n';

    char c1 = 'A';
    char c2 = 'Z';

    std::cout << "c1 is " << c1 << '\n'; 
    std::cout << "x2 is " << c2 << '\n'; 
    std::cout << '\n';

    swap( c1, c2 );

    std::cout << "c1 is " << c1 << '\n'; 
    std::cout << "x2 is " << c2 << '\n'; 
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

The program output is

```
str1 is GEEKS
str2 is FOR GEEKS

str1 is FOR GEEKS
str2 is GEEKS

c1 is A
x2 is Z

c1 is Z
x2 is A
```

So in the first call of `swap` the referenced type is `const char *`. In the second call of `swap`the referenced type is `char`.

Answer (score 2):

It's a reference to a pointer. That way the function can access not only what the pointer *points to*, but can also modify the passed in pointer itself (it can change what the passed in pointer points to, so it points to something else).

Answer (score 2):

If you pass a reference to integer to a swap function, you will be copying one variable’s data to other just like this:

```
void swap(int &a, int &b) 
{ 
    int temp = a; 
    a = b; 
    b = temp;
} 

int main() 
{ 
    int a = 1; 
    int b = 5; 
    std::cout<<"a's adress before swap: "<< &a <<'\n'; 
    std::cout<<"b's adress before swap: "<< &b <<'\n'; 
    swap(a, b); 
    std::cout<<"a's adress after swap: "<< &a <<'\n'; 
    std::cout<<"b's adress after swap: "<< &b <<'\n'; 
    return 0; 
}
```

The output is:

```
a's adress before swap: 0x7ffeeccaba68
b's adress before swap: 0x7ffeeccaba64
a's adress after swap: 0x7ffeeccaba68
b's adress after swap: 0x7ffeeccaba64
```

So it copied `a’s` data to `temp`, then copied `b’s` data to `a`, finally copied `temp’s` data to `b`. It is okay if you’re passing small objects like integers, however it may cost a significant time and space if you pass big objects like Class objects to swap function.

On the other hand, if you pass a reference to pointer to a swap function, you will be just chancing where pointers are pointing. For example:

```
#include <iostream>
void swap(int *&a, int *&b){
    int *temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}

int main(){
    int x = 1;
    int y = 5;
    int *a = &x;
    int *b = &y;
    std::cout << "where a points before swap: " << a << '\n';
    std::cout << "where b points before swap: "<< b << '\n';
    swap(a, b);
    std::cout << "where a points after swap: " << a << '\n';
    std::cout << "where b points after swap: "<< b << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Notice that in the output, where `a` and `b` points chancing after `swap`:

```
where a points before swap: 0x7ffee1738a68
where b points before swap: 0x7ffee1738a64
where a points after swap: 0x7ffee1738a64
where b points after swap: 0x7ffee1738a68
```

In the swap function, firstly `temp` points where `a`(pointing `x`) points, then `a` points where `b`(pointing `y`) points, finally `b` points where `temp` points( pointing `x`). Thus, it just swapped where pointers are pointing and didn’t copy any significant data. So if you need to swap big data objects reference to a pointer is better for time and space.

Answer (score 1):

Passing a reference to a pointer is much like passing a reference to any other type of variable. So, in the function:

```cpp
void swap(char * &str1, char * &str2) {
\\..
```

the *types* of the two arguments are `char*` (pointer-to-characters, or C-style strings).

In reality, the *reference* is actually the *address* of each argument so, when the function 'swaps' the pointers, the swapping is also effective in the calling code.

If the arguments were simply `char*` (rather than `char* &`), then the 'pointers' passed would be **copies** of their values in the calling code, and anything done on/with them in the function would have no effect in that calling code. (But note: the function *can* still change the data *pointed to* by the arguments - it just can't change/modify the actual pointers, as it needs to!)

However, in your 'suggested alternative', where you have:

```cpp
void swap(char &str1, char &str2) {
//..
```

you are changing the actual **type** of the arguments! Here, you are passing *references to* (i.e. *addresses of*) single characters (`char` variables), rather than the (start addresses of) character strings.

Comment: I'm curious why do they output the same results?

Comment: @Phineas And I'm curious why the second version even compiles!

Comment: @Phineas ... unless, of course, you have **both** function definitions in your code, in which case you have what's known as *overloading* - and the compiler will use the one that (best) matches the call, which will be the 'original' one, in your case (so the second function isn't even used).

Comment: nope, perfectly fine, only 1 function, compiled on Visual Studio. 
 (http://cpp.sh/3pie4)

Comment: @Phineas Your problem lies with the line `using namespace std;` - this defines its own `swap` function which is being used in place of the one you provide. See here: [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/10871073).

Comment: Add a `std::cout << "My function" << std::endl;` line in your function, and you will see that it is never called. @Phineas

Comment: yes, I've just realized, it uses the its `std::swap`. Thanks a lot